# How to highlight a point without using any event or action in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How to highlight a point or how to represent a point with colour dynamically while chart loading and without performing any event [It's Not like mouse over, mouse out or click].

Please help in this regard and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want some points to be in different color than remaining points in the series??

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want this behaviour based on some condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply mention the color for the point right at the value itself. that will give the color to that point.

```
        data: [{
            y: 29.9,
            color: 'red'
        }, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
```

Here the first point will be red and all other points will be of default color.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rvdh45pb/) is a working example for the same

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can chose any point and call `setState` function.

```
chart.series[0].data[1].setState('hover');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rqao9dq7/